# A question/confusion regarding branch cuts

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I had a problem in finding the branch cut as I understand that

$$
(z^2-1)^{-1/2} 
$$
will have a branch cut between $[-1,1]$ after checking the arguments. But does the following have a break at 0?
$$
z^{-1}(z^2-1)^{-1/2}
$$
I am asking as I am trying to prove the following question and found that we shall have a break at 0. However I am not sure.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1}(x^2-1)^{-1/2}=\pi/2
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the author of the question and trying to answer it myself as I think I understood it. I went though some books and saw that we can have multiple ways to construct branch cuts for the same expression/function. For example we can take a branch cut for $z^{1/2}$ between 0,∞ or 0,−∞ since there is no sense of infinity in complex analysis in terms of direction. You may traverse along any direction to get a a branch cut provided you have the Riemann sheets for the function/expression.

In the case above, there shall indeed be a branch cut between 1,-1 without any break provided you consider the Branch cut from 1,∞ for $(z-1)^{1/2}$ and from -1,∞ for $(z+1)^{1/2}$. There $\textbf{won't be any break at the point 0}$ as we see a change in arg(z) about z=0 above and below the axes and hence a branch cut. The moment I tell about arg(z), I mean that we are talking about 2 different riemann sheets. If the arg(z) above and below the axes are same, we mean that we are on the same sheet and hence we get no branch cut. Although in our case, we see that there must be a $\pi$ phase difference between the above and below of the axes. And since there is a phase difference, we don't see any kind of discontinuity /break in the branch point. And coming to the singularity (If there was a confusion about the question that I was asking about the singularity), the function has singularity at z=0 and is perfectly continuous in (-1,1) except for 0.

For more references regarding the way you should take the branch cuts, you can refer this:
https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.305/Notes/n00Branch_Points_B_Cuts.pdf

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).